# How to configure CORS in spring boot with spring security?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, cors

I have a problem with the CORS. I have the following configuration of security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomJwtAuthenticationFilter customJwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT","OPTIONS","PATCH", "DELETE"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/helloadmin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/hellouser").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/techshop/web/v1/product/save").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("techshop/web/v1/product").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("techshop/web/v1/product/{id}").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling()
                //if any exception occurs call this
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

                //Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
                http.addFilterBefore((Filter) customJwtAuthenticationFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

And I have the following controllers:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @PostMapping(path = "/authenticate",  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request) throws Exception {
        try{
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLE", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e){
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
        }
        final UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(request.getUsername());
        final String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(token));
    }

}
```

And:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("techshop/web/v1")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductServiceI productService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/product/save", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> save(@RequestBody ProductDto request){
        productService.save(request);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/product", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> findAll(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.findAll());
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/product/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateProduct(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody ProductDto request){
        productService.update(request, id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/product/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteById(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        productService.deletedById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

When I make the following request, the browser show the CORS problem:

```
let datos = {
    username:"admin",
    password:"admin"
}

const getToken = () => {
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'localhost:8080/test',
        data: datos
        });
}

getToken()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuwdT.png)

I've tried everything, with the @CrosOrigin ("*") annotation, with lambdas, with a Bean WebConfig that extends from corsConfigurer, but nothing works.

I appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```js
const getToken = () => {
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/test',
        data: datos
        });
}
```